# Proving that family of finite subsets is a ring of sets

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

There is a set X given. I am to proof that the family $\mathbb{F}$ of all finite subsets of X is a ring of sets.
What I know is that a ring of sets must follow three conditions:
1) $\emptyset \in R$
2) if $A, B \in R \rightarrow A \cup B\in R$
3) if $A, B \in R \rightarrow A \setminus B\in R$
where $R$ is the ring of sets.
However I don't know how the proof should look like. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Is $\emptyset$ a *finite* set ?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are *finite* sets, will $A \cup B$ be finite ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, $\emptyset$ is a finite set.

Comment: The same for 2 and 3, based on intuition. For a formal proof, we need the def of *finite* set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However I don't know how the proof should look like.

You need to address these questions:

1. Is $\emptyset$ a finite subset of $X$?
2. If $A,B$ are finite subsets of $X$, are $A\cup B$ and $A\setminus B$ finite subsets of $X$?

If you demonstrate all of these in the affirmative, you will have proven $\mathbb F$ is a ring of sets.

Comment: Yes. They are finite but how to show that? I know only that $A,B$ are finite so I think I am to transcribe $A\cupB$ to a form where I can use that both $A, B$ are finite. I don't know how however.

Comment: @Hendrra It sounds like you are missing some very basic knowledge of counting sets. You should really look into the equation $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$. At the very least, intuitively, you should understand why $|A\cup B|\leq |A|+|B|$. (The vertical bars here all stand for "number of elements")

Comment: Thanks! Now I got it :)